# Is Violet Evergarden a robot, a cyborg or a human?

Tags: violet-evergarden

So far, two episodes are out, and the following observations about Violet Evergarden are made:

1. She wants to learn what "I love you" means, a common trope among AI and other robotic characters.
2. She used to have human arms, but lost them during the Four-Year War.
3. In episode 2 when she was having dinner, we only saw her cut the fish awkwardly, but not eat or drink even once.
4. She's used to work long hours and her choice of word for eating and sleeping, "recharge", is not intended for humans.

So what is she, exactly?

Answer (score 14):

She is human. This can be further proven by the fact that:

1. She can bleed. As seen during the flashbacks of the war from several episodes, namely one and two. If it was oil, it would've been black; which it wasn't.
2. She has emotions. She was worried about Major Gilbert and was curious about the meaning of the phrase, 'I love you' and how it made her feel.

She only looks like a robot because of her mechanical arms. She lost her human arms during the war. She is only awkward, because she never understood how to interact with other individuals in a normal society. She only knows how to act like a soldier.

Answer (score 5):

She is indeed a human, but her awkward social skills are due to her being in the army from her very childhood (since she was 10 y/o). She lived as a soldier and never really got to experience the world as a normal girl.

Answer (score 3):

Violet is confirmed to be human in Episode 10.

> In episode 10, Violet meets Anne Magnolia.  It is established early in the episode that Anne is a huge fan of dolls, most likely because she cannot spend as much time with her sickly mother. Upon seeing Violet, Anne believes that Violet is a real doll, both in her appearance and as her title of Auto-Memory Doll. This is also further supported by Violet's mechanical arms and when Violet explains that when she uses the bathroom "it returns to the Earth".
> When Violet is leaving, Anne kisses Violet's cheek, remarking that it is warm. We watch as Anne suddenly realizes that she had made a mistake.  Anne is unable to finish her question, bur she is most likely asking Violet if she is human. When Violet nods, Anne is embarrassed and runs away.

Answer (score 2):

Violet is a human girl. In the first episode of season one, she starts in the hospital. If she was a robot she would most likely just be rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are leaving it purposely ambiguous.  But I don’t think she’s human, not fully.  You never see her eat, and only drink tea.  When she lost her arms in battle, she did not act AT ALL like a young girl who got horribly maimed.  If she were human, she would have bled out.  There has to be a reason Captain Bouganville treats her so poorly and adamantly refers to her as a tool.  And a reason she can regularly best trained soldiers.  I think she might be a cyborg akin to the T-800, with an organic shell.

Answer (score 0):

Violet is human, however, she doesn’t really know how to act around people nor socialize properly due to being raised in the military.

Answer (score 0):

Violet is human, it isn't obvious at the start, but as her emotions are explored later on, it becomes even more prominent.
I think the makers intended for viewers to be confused at the start because of her mechanical arms as well as emotionless attitude. This was because she lived all her life either on the streets or in the army. 
Also as seen from the flashbacks she can indeed bleed like humans.

Comment: Can you provide any sources?

Answer (score 0):

Violet Evergarden is indeed a human, just because shes socially awkward and doesn't eat doesn't mean anything. Violet was in the army at such a young age and was only taught how to act like a soldier, She must've went through a hard time because she lost her arms. Also she was bleeding in a couple of the other scenes so she has to be a human, If she was a cyborg, robot she would defiantly have black oil coming out of her but that didn't happen.